# Responsive font icon is it possible?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, icons

I'm trying to replace no-img image with font icon to be size img independent.
Here is example: http://codepen.io/piernik/pen/huHCg

Now shrink screen below 500px. How to make it responsive?
With `img` tag all You had to do is give `img width:100%`. How to do it with font icon and `i` tag?

I know that I could use `@media` element from CSS but it's not good solution - I don't want change font size in steps (max 700px, max 400px and so on). I want it to shrink fluid.

Comment: Not yet. Your solution is good, but it's not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve the camera shape with **CSS only** and make it responsive by using percentage height/width :

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/dqmKt)**

output :

[image: CSS responsive camera icon]

*HTML :*

```
<div class="camera"><div class="circle"></div></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
.camera{
  position:relative;
  width:70%;
  margin:20% auto;
  background-color:#444444;
  padding-bottom:50%;
  border-radius:15%;
}
.camera:before, .camera:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:90%;
  background-color:inherit;
  height:25%; width:25%;
  border-radius:25%;
}
.camera:before{
  right:45%;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-15deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-15deg);
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
}
.camera:after{
  left:45%;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(15deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(15deg);
  transform: skewX(15deg);
}
.circle{
  position:absolute;
  left:30%; top:20%;
  width:40%;
  padding-bottom:40%;
  background:#EEEEEE;
  border-radius:50%;
}
.circle:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:15%; left:15%;
  width:70%; height:70%;
  background-color:#444444;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something involving scaling the font-size dynamically, based on the window size. Check out this [**page**](http://www.dotticontra.org/devel/javascript/jquery_dynamic_font_resize_demo/).